# To solve system of linear inequalities graphically SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, inequality

I've got system of linear inequalities:
y > 0.5x + 7, y >= 5, x >= 4.
I need to get graphical solution, like at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3E0.5x%20%2B%207%2C%20y%3E%3D5%2C%20x%3E%3D4).
I've found that SymPy can be used,here is what I've done:

```
X = symbols('x') 
Y = symbols('y') 
res = solve((-y + 0.5 * x + 7, -y + 5, -x + 4),  x, y) 
res
```

But the output is empty: [].
Anyway, I have no idea how to get polygon solution.
I've tried also:

```
X = symbols('x') 
Y = symbols('y') 
res = solve((y > 0.5 * x + 7, y > 5, x > 4),  x) 
plot_implicit(-y < -0.5 * x - 7, -y<=-5, -x<=-4)
```

The error: **TypeError: object of type 'LessThan' has no len()**
How can I get the correct result on the graph?

Answer (score -1):

first you should look for : solve_rational_inequalities